# Indirect Formula getting the value from a variable instead of a cell range?

Tags: excel, vba

i have a problem. I am doing a spreadsheet with some images that change between two colors, depending on a value of a cell. So i used the indirect formula in the image. The thing is that cell can only take to options, making the image red or green.

So i can do it. The problem is that i have 50 images so i need 50 indirect formulas for each image, and for each formula i need one range cell in a worksheets called "Variables"

To assign the correct code to those ranges (1 or 0 for example) i created a code with 50 variables (im1, im2, im3...) that change when i end the task for each image.

The code is working fine. But... because i have 50 variables i takes to much time to excel everytime it has to change the value of the cell in Sheets("Variables") for the image to change color.

This idle time of the workbook is killing it, so i wanted to see if there is a possibility to instead of making the indirect formula go to the value in the cell in Sheets("Variables") go directy to the value of the variable (im1,im2...) that i have in the code. This would make the program faster because i wouldnt need to change in the sheet everytime a variable change state.

Comment: If it's only two colors in your images, why not using conditional format?

Comment: You could start your formula in the image with =if(range("a1")=1;...your formula here...  when A1 = 1 your images will be recalculated, otherwise not

Comment: I could do that, but that i can do alright with the indirect. I don't want to use the range("A1") i want to use the variable in the macro instead. The macro is running low because of the passage of the variables values to the worksheets ranges.

Comment: If you are already running code, why the usage of the Indirect-formula? Could you show your VBA code and formula(s) as well in your openings-post?

Comment: Would be a lot easier to understand what you're trying if we could see your code.  Using 50 variables sounds like you're making extra work for yourself.

Comment: I am sorry i didn't said anything later. I solved it, and decided to not use the indirect formula, i still have the 50 variables because all of them are for a diferent excel shape, but i am studying a fuction with one variable that will change the shape accordingly with the value of the shape i am changing. I will say something later.